# How to find trigger ID in Zabbix GUI?

Tags: zabbix

1. Is it possible to find a trigger's ID in the GUI or is it only possible via the API?
2. Also, does the ID refer to the trigger on a template level or host?
3. Can I just disable the trigger on a host and not on the entire template?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to find a triggers ID in the GUI or is it only via the API?

Open a trigger configuration and check "triggerid" in the URL.

> Also does the ID refer to the trigger on a template level or host?

In the previous step, if you have opened a trigger at the host level, the trigger ID is for the host trigger. If you have opened a trigger at the template level, the trigger ID is for the template trigger.

> Id can I just disable the trigger on a host and not the entire
>   template?

Yes, you can. When viewing triggers for a host, just click "Enabled" link on the right of the trigger. Alternatively, select multiple triggers and choose "Enable selected" on the bottom left.